# Are "phonics" and "Phoenician" related?

Tags: etymology, phonetics, phrase-origin

I was watching a history lecture recently, and the professor stated that after the Greek "dark ages," during which their previously used written language was lost and forgotten, a new written language was developed by essentially stealing the pre-existing Phoenician alphabet and assigning sounds to each of the letters.

This is the earliest documented use of a phonetic alphabet in history (that I know of), and it occurred to me that the words "Phonics" and "Phoenician" might be related; in fact, this relationship makes it seem extremely unlikely that there is no relationship between the terms.

Can anyone explain the similarities between these words, and determine whether my guess is correct?

Comment: Yep, somewhere around the 5th grade I was taught that the Phoneticians invented the concept of an alphabet of sounds, and hence they created "phonetics".  Pretty sure you could find this if you looked on some sort of search thingie on some kind of electrical gizmo.

Comment: Not an answer at all but ['boat'](https://www.etymonline.com/word/boat) and ['boot'](https://www.etymonline.com/word/boot#etymonline_v_15614) are almost identical but have different sources. Just because two words sound the same doesn't mean they are related (they may be, but there's no guarantee).

Comment: @Mitch Right, that's why I'm asking. "Boat" and "boot" sound the same, but they don't have the uncanny historical relationship like that between "phonetic" and "Phoenician" that I described in my question.

Comment: @Frpzzd I think your suggestion is that the name 'Phoenician' (or really the original Greek) was coined by the Greeks for them (what they called themselves is unknown). And because the Greeks borrowed the Phoenician writing system, and metonymically labeled them after a Greek word associated with an alphabet, namely 'phone-', or sound.  The metonym process is not a difficulty, the difficulty is data. The data (currently) supports the Greek word for 'red dye' as the source.

Comment: This question not seem to be about the English Language, but about Phoenician, Greek and Latin.

Comment: @Mitch, there's no indication that this were the case and I understood it the opposite way to derive phone from phoenician. Mycenaeaen (viz. Greek) Linear B inscriptions already recorded the ethonym  adj. (po-ni-ki-ja) as adjective, probably from Egyptian, long before introduction of the Greek alphabet. The premisses for *phone* are more difficult to summarize in a short comment.

Comment: CVd on lack-of-research-shown grounds.

Comment: *Are "phonics" and "Phoenician" related?* What was the Phoenician for "phonics"?

Comment: Yes, that's my logical conclusion. Phoenician was Greek exonym & the name had no original meaning for the Romans & French that passed the terms to the English. For the Romans/French, the Phoenician alphabet they used was related to the representation of the phonetic sounds (A as Aleph, B as Beth...) vs the earlier symbolic scripts. So, from Greek 'phonein' speak, to Latin phoneticus & French /English phonème interpretation, the "purple" hypothesis is losing it's meaning

Answer (score 15):

Etymology is much, much more complicated than most people think! Just because words sound similar, that doesn't mean they are related. In this case, chances are negligible that they should be.

Greek **φωνή** "voice" is spelled with **an omega**, whereas **φοῖνιξ** "Phoenician" is spelled with **an omicron and an iota**. Those letters represent very different vowels in Greek, and there are no phonological rules that I know of by which one could shift into the other. So that alone makes it very unlikely.

Further, the conexion between the Phoenician people, with whom the Greeks were in frequent and extensive contact, and the **origin of the alphabet was not that important to the Greeks**; they borrowed so many other things from the Phoenicians, of which the alphabet was only one. It would be like saying **that the English word *language* must be related to the word *Latin***, because that is where English borrowed its alphabet from and the two words sound somewhat similar. Or that Dutch *talen* "languages" must be from *Latijn* "Latin", because they sound similar and the Dutch borrowed their alphabet from Latin. None of those things are true, and the similar sound is coincidental.

Lastly, the well respected etymological dictionary of Greek by Chantraine says that **φωνή** is probably from a Proto-Indo-European root *bho- meaning something like **"sound"**; but that **φοῖνιξ** "Phoenician" is probably either from φοινός **"(blood) red"**, because the skin tone of the Phoenicians was perceived to be "dark red", or from an unknown (and unattested) Phoenician word, or yet from an unknown word in an older substrate language. Note that φοινός "blood red" is probably not from φόνος "murder", still according to Chantraine, despite the apparent semantic similarity.

Answer (score 11):

This is a very vexed area, in which the chances of certainty are slight for the simple reason that it becomes progressively harder to determine exact pronunciation that far back.

However, I am afraid there is no connection between ‘Phoenician’ and ‘phonic’.

- ‘φοινοσ’ refers to a deep red luxury dye made from murex shells, in which Phoenician merchants traded most profitably.
- The word *phonetic* is of Greek origin (φωνή {phōni} = voice).

Greek writing probably first emerged in the 8th century BCE.  What its predecessors appear to have lacked, namely the Phoenician alphabet, was a comprehensive representation of vowel as well as consonant sounds.  We still find this in Hebrew and Arabic scripts, where the diacritical marks to indicate vowel sounds are a relatively modern development.

Greek had 7 vowels:  Α (A), Ε (E), Η (pronounced ‘air’ in ancient times but ‘ee’ now), Ι, Ο, Υ (pronounced more like the French ‘u’), Ω (pronounced like ‘awe’).

In addition there were various diphthongs:  AI (as in ‘eye’), AU (as in ‘how’), EI (as in ‘eight’), OI (as in ‘joy’), OU (as in shoe’).

These vowels, in turn, made it easy to record the different dialects of the language, which were driven as much as by anything by local differences of pronunciation.

Much, possibly too much, has been made of the Greek ‘invention’ of a phonetic alphabet, when the predecessors did have sounds associated with their letters.  Still, it is true that the voiced vowels were a significant development.

Comment: Eta was perhaps pronounced as ‘air’ in some specific dialects, but to most English-speakers, the two will sound fairly different. Similarly, ypsilon was pronounced like French <u>, not like French <i>.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, I’m sorry about missing the ‘u’ and hitting the ‘i’ .  I shall edit accordingly.  ‘air’ (British English with non-rhotic ‘r’ was the nearest I could get.  I am sorry. not to have though of US pronunciation.

Comment: The Indians were in the process of inventing real scientific phonetics at the same time the Greeks were squabbling in the Peloponnesus. Pronunciation ***mattered*** when chanting the Vedas.

Comment: "what its predecessor seems to have lacked" is irrelevant if you mean the levantine and Gyptian writing systems, because the predecessor of Greek Writing would be recording Mycenaean in Linear B, which is a syllabary that has represented vowels, long ago.

Answer (score 0):

One cannot simply state that an ancient people pronounced anything "just so" without taking into consideration the following factors.... 1. idioms, dialects and pronunciations of the same language can vary tremendously from village to village, and even within large cities.
2. languages constantly absorb bits of other languages, thereby corrupting pronunciation.
3. Such loan words frequently incur letter shifts.
The Phoenicians were an extremely cosmopolitan bunch of traveling traders, who developed a language that was understood by the majority of Mediterranean people's.
Having been a paneuropean trader for 40 odd years I have first hand experience in how this works. NOBODY can ascertain the truth of the matter postulated, but I love it. Auf revoir derci the noo

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: True, but mentioning dialectal variation in historical linguistics is +1 for me. We have to keep in mind that real languages vary.

Answer (score -3):

Your assumption is practically valid, but hard to prove. Also hard to disprove because we don't know how Greek Phonic entered the Greek language.

We have little (documented) knowledge of the sources that entered into the Greek language & assume many words are of Greek origin, while diminishing the Eastern civilisations value. Most of the communication was oral & lost for tracing back the real origins.

Future AI, data science can help discover more relationships. Until then, it all looks Greek to many. :)

Comment: [Easter civilizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ēostre) always surprise me. But this seems more of a comment than it does an answer.

Comment: "European agenda"? Please keep Brexit out of this list.

Comment: Try to read without emotional overreaction, please. Many assumptions are made without real proof. Most of the communication was oral & lost for tracing back the real origins.